# How do I see someone moving near speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, observers

I have zero knowledge of physics, so sorry for the newb question. I was wondering, after watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AInCqm5nCzw), if I'm looking at a person travelling near the speed of light, would I see him not moving at all since his time slowed down drastically?

Comment: with my understanding, you will see something moving very fast. Time slowed down for an object moving so fast, not for observer watching it.

Comment: But like, it would make sense that the stationary person is witnessing the person travelling at the speed of light moving very slowly. This way, after that person went from the moon to the earth, the stationary person has aged say ten years.

Comment: It really matters what you mean by "see", as this causes all kinds of trouble for SR noobs. Here are some options: 1) what do your human eyes see 2) what does your sophisticated PHz hyper spectral sensor see in realtime 3) what does your networked of stationary synchronized and calibrated sensors reconstruct after the fact 4) what to world-line  seeing 4D bulk-beings "see" (hypothetically).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The person would be travelling at almost 300,000,000 metres per second. Supposing they approached you in a straight line, how close would a person have to get before you could make them out? To make the maths easy, let's say that you can see a person as a tiny dot when they are 30km away. From that distance it would take some travelling at near light speed one ten-thousandth of a second to reach you. Another ten thousandth of a second later they would be 30km beyond you. Those time periods are much shorter than the reaction time of the human eye, so in reality you wouldn't see anything whatsoever.

Comment: This needs to be pointed out more often ;)  Either it hits you in the eye, or you have to track it.  Try it with a bullet, about a million times slower!

Comment: I’m still wondering, since he is travelling at near speed of light, wouldn’t his time tick much slower than mine? So then his one second is say ten year to me. So then he travel the distance of light in one second will be witnessed by me as travelling for 10 year??

Comment: In your frame of reference, the person will travel nearly ten light years in ten years. In their frame of reference, they are not moving. They will think you are flashing past at close to the speed of light, and that your clock is running slow. The effects are entirely reciprocal between the two frames of reference.